# Custom UISwitch Design

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I want to create design for Switch like below image.
Is that possible to Modify UISwitch? or I need to use any other way.

[image]

Comment: Check "customising the appearance of the switch" at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch

Comment: you need to create custom UISwitch you did not get the required output in default UISwitch.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible to Modify UISwitch?

In iOS 6 and earlier, you could set the `onImage` and `offImage` properties. But since we're now working with iOS 13, that solution stopped working a long time ago.

> I want to create design for Switch like below image.

A switch is just a control with two states... rolling your own should be a straightforward matter of subclassing UIControl. Look at the *Subclassing* section of the [UIControl documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol) for information about the methods you need to override to make your switch work as a control.

Your switch could be as simple as a view that can draw itself in either of two states, so to get started you could create a view that has two images and draws the appropriate one depending on its state. But UISwitch animates the transition between the two states, and there's a lot of subtlety that you might not have noticed. Making your switch work look as good, or nearly as good, will take more work. Look at how the background color fades in and out as a UISwitch is turned on and off, and notice that on devices that support haptic feedback, the device gives off a pulse as the switch changes state.

For your custom switch, you'll probably want to use Core Animation to move a view or layer representing the switches thumb over a background that has the icons representing the two states. [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer) has a
number of features that could be helpful.